# How to export/import a C struct from a DLL/ to a console application using __declspec( dllexport/import )

Tags: c, dll, struct, dllimport, dllexport

This is my first time dealing with DLLs. Following the MSDN documentation I created a header file **fooExports.h** with macros defined according to a preprocessor definition:

```
#ifdef FOODLL_EXPORTS
    #define FOO_API __declspec( dllexport )
#else
    #define FOO_API __declspec( dllimport )
```

My intention was to use this header both in my DLL implementation as well as in the console application. So far importing and exporting functions works just fine. The problem arrises when I try to export an already defined struct that I need as parameter for one of the exported functions. For example, in the aforementioned header file I declare `FOO_API void foo( FooParams *args )` and `args` is a struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct FooParams
{
    char *a;
    char *b;
    void *whatever; //some other type
} FooParams;
```

This struct has to be defined in **foo.h** rather than in **fooExports.h**. Is there any way to export this struct without taking it out of it's original header file (taking into consideration that I want to keep the exports/imports centralized in **fooExports.h**).
What would be a better approach to doing this? The DLL is all C as well as the client application using it.

Comment: You don't export types, you export linker symbols.

Comment: @aschepler would you mind expanding on that?

Comment: It isn't at all clear why you used two .h files or why you just didn't declare the argument type for foo().  There's nothing to export in the struct, it doesn't have any code.  The simple way to avoid the dilemma is to just use one .h file and be done with it.

Comment: @HansPassant I fixed the type of the parameter as you suggested. The reason why I don't want just one header file is because the export header file is going to be shared with both the client and the DLL and I don't want to expose the declaration of all my structs in that header.

Comment: You want the client code to see __declspec(dllimport) *and* FooParams.  So everything you posted so far belongs in one .h file.  If you have other .h files that are specific to the implementation then just #include them in your .cpp files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the only use the client will ever have for `FooParams` is to get pointers to it returned from DLL functions and to pass those pointers to other DLL functions, you can make it an "opaque type": Put

```
typedef struct FooParams FooParams;
```

in fooExports.h.  The `FOO_API` macro does not belong on that declaration.  An opaque type means the client code cannot:

- Create any variables of type `FooParams` (but `FooParams * ptr = NULL;` is okay).
- Do anything at all with any member of `FooParams`.
- Find `sizeof(FooParams)` - and therefore cannot correctly `malloc` space for one or more `FooParams` objects.

You can't `#define` macros visible to the client which do any of the above, either.  So your DLL would need to have one or more "constructor" or "factory" functions, maybe something like

```
FOO_API FooParams* CreateFooParams(const char * input);
```

It's also good practice to define a matching "destructor" function like

```
FOO_API void DestroyFooParams(FooParams * p);
```

*even if* the definition is as simple as `{ free(p); }`, because there can sometimes be issues if memory allocated inside a DLL is freed by code outside it or vice versa (because not all Windows code uses identical definitions of `malloc` and `free`).

If all this is too extreme, the only other option is to put or `#include` the `struct` definition in the exported header file and make it visible to clients.  Without that, any attempt to do something to a `FooParams`, other than passing pointers around, is going to be impossible because the compiler won't know what's in a `FooParams`.  The compiler (as opposed to the linker) takes information only from commandline arguments and `#include`-d files, not from libraries or DLLs.

Comment: thank you so much. this is a great answer! While waiting for a response I intuitively took the approach of `including` my headers with the struct definitions in the client. Just wanted to make sure there was no other way. And as you just explained, there isn't for what I need to do. thanks again for your time!