# Returning structs by value across DLL-exported class' method - is it safe?

Tags: c++, dll, struct

I'm trying to use a public class method to return some data via structs. The structs have simple c'tors and stateless methods, and some even contain other structs (no C++/STL types though). The class and structs will be exported to DLL.

The entire definition for the structs are contained in headers with the appropriate `dllexport` or `dllimport` modifiers because they are meant to be used by clients, who will have the static import libraries as well.

Snippets as follows:

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) Data
{
    double dataA;
    double dataB;

    Data(double _a, double _b) : dataA(_a), dataB(_b) {}
    double helperMethod(double param1, double param2) { return dataA + dataB; }
};

struct __declspec(dllexport) AggData
{
    double dataX;
    double dataY;
    Data aStructData;

    AggData(double _x, double _y) : dataX(_x), dataY(_y), aStructData(0.0, 0.0) {}
    double helperMethod(double param1, double param2) { return dataX + dataY; }
};

class __declspec(dllexport) IModel
{
public:
    virtual Data returnSomeData() = 0;
    virtual AggData returnSomeOtherData() = 0;
};

class __declspec(dllexport) Model : public IModel
{
public:
    Data returnSomeData();
    AggData returnSomeOtherData();
};
```

**My main question is**: Do the headers and the import libraries guarantee that clients can use my classes as intended, i.e., no corruption of data due to ABI issues?

This question and its answer seemed close to what I'm looking for, but there's no mention of whether an import library can solve the virtual function issue:
[Passing struct by value from an explicitly loaded dll built with a different compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155857/passing-struct-by-value-from-an-explicitly-loaded-dll-built-with-a-different-com)

**A related question**: If I distributed only the headers without import libraries, and assuming there were no virtual functions, will it be sufficient for use? I think this is just a question about struct memory layout across compilers, but I'm not clear on it either.

Read these other questions, but didn't quite see an answer (or didn't realise if I saw one):
[C++ define class member struct and return it in a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523109/c-define-class-member-struct-and-return-it-in-a-member-function)
[How to export/import a C struct from a DLL/ to a console application using __declspec( dllexport/import )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342138/how-to-export-import-a-c-struct-from-a-dll-to-a-console-application-using-dec)

Comment: You can't get "is it safe" guarantees here, nor from the import library.  The client code should use the same compiler version with the exact same settings when you export C++ classes.  With the shared CRT version so there's only one copy of the CRT in the process, /MD compile option in MSVC++.

Comment: Not only that, but you limit your ability to change the struct in the future without requiring all clients to recompile. That means that older clients won't work with newer versions of the library and vice-versa. If you are going to do that, I recommend having a version member in the struct so clients can tell if the data they're getting back is in a format they can understand.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, I would accept that as the answer if I could.

Comment: @user1118321: Do you mean that I could expand the struct and clients using an older version could still read the data defined in their version? I thought that only worked for serialised data.

Comment: If the size of the struct changes, then older clients won't be able to work at all because they'll push and pop the wrong number of bytes on the stack during calls and returns. But if you're careful about creating the structs, you can do things like leave space at the end for future expansion. (You'll often see stuff like `char reserved [10];` so you have 10 extra bytes you can use later.) In that case, versioning the struct allows older clients to at least know that the data is newer than they can handle, or potentially use only the parts they know about.